# encoding error when reading excel file

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I want to go through data in my folder, identify them and rename them according to a list of rules I have in an excel spreadsheet
I load the needed libraries, 
I make my directory the working directory; 
I read in the xcel file (using xlrd)
and when I try to read the data by columns e.g. :

```
fname = metadata.col_values(0, start_rowx=1, end_rowx=None)
```

the list of values comes with a `u` in front of them - I guess unicode - such as:
fname = [u'file1', u'file2'] and so on

How can I convert fname to a list of ascii strings?

Comment: what's the big deal if the strings are in unicode?

Comment: thanks for the comments / suggestions; I am not sure if the unicode is the problem, but I think this is the problem since the code cannot identify file1, file2 etc in my folder --I believe the error was the presence of u

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the big issue behind having unicode filenames is, but assuming that all of your characters are ascii-valid characters the following should do it. This solution will just ignore anything that's non-ascii, but it's worth thinking about why you're doing this in the first place:

```
ascii_string = unicode_string.encode("ascii", "ignore")
```

Specifically, for converting a whole list I would use a list comprehension:

```
ascii_list = [old_string.encode("ascii", "ignore") for old_string in fname]
```

Comment: thank - probably your are right, and unicode is not the problem with the code; I will test and update the code - I will post the results

Answer (score 0):

The `u` at the front is just a visual item to show you, when you print the string, what the underlying representation is. It's like the single-quotes around the strings when you print that list--they are there to show you something about the object being printed (specifically, that it's a string), but they aren't actually a part of the object.

In the case of the `u`, it's saying it's a unicode object. When you use the string internally, that `u` on the outside doesn't exist, just like the single-quotes. Try opening a file and writing the strings there, and you'll see that the `u` and the single-quotes don't show up, because they're not actually part of the underlying string objects.

```
with open(r'C:\test\foo.bar', 'w') as f:
    for item in fname:
        f.write(item)
        f.write('\n')
```

If you really need to print strings without the `u` at the start, you can convert them to ASCII with `u'unicode stuff'.encode('ascii')`, but honestly I doubt this is something that actually matters for what you're doing.

You could also just use Python 3, where Unicode is the default and the `u` isn't normally printed.

Comment: thanks - I now believe unicode might not be my problem; I will update the post as soon as I know better

Comment: `f.write(item)` fails if `item` is a Unicode string with characters outside `ascii` (`sys.getdefaultencoding()`). Use `codecs.open()` with explicit character encoding instead.